# Change alpha value for certain break values in ggplot geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a scatter plot from 100k++ points and i would like the colour points (break values 1 and 2 which are "green" and break value 20 which is "red") to stand out more than the "cornsilk1" points (break values 3 to 19). I have tried the code below but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks so much

p.s. please excuse my juvenile code. I am sure there is a way more effective way to do this...

```
plotIA<-ggplot(plotintaobs,aes(x=SD13009PB,y=SD13009PB2,colour=quartile))+geom_point()+labs(x="Phillips Observeration 1", y="Phillips Observation 2") + ggtitle("Intra-observer Variation") + mytheme  


plotIA+ scale_color_manual(breaks = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"), 
values=c("green","green", "cornsilk1", "cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","cornsilk1","red"))

plotIA+scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1,1,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,1))
```

Comment: Could you please post `dput(plotintaobs)`? juvenile is OK, however you are encouraged to post reproducible examples: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Probably `aes(..., alpha = quartile )` solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately dput(plotintaobs) is too large to post. But aes(..., alpha = quartile ) worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy is to use `cut` to split the quartiles into into your three groups. Then you can use scale_colour_manual

```
# some fake data
plotintaobs <- data.frame(SD13009PB = rnorm(20), SD13009PB2 = rnorm(20), quartile = 1:20) 

#cut quartile
plotintaobs$q2 <- cut(plotintaobs$quartile, breaks = c(0, 2, 19, 20), labels = c("low", "mid", "high"))

#plot
plotIA <- ggplot(plotintaobs, aes(x = SD13009PB, y = SD13009PB2, colour = q2, alpha = q2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("green", "cornsilk1","red")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0.8, 1))

plotIA
```